# 403 when trying to deploy Flask app on GoDaddy

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, cgi, web-hosting

I'm getting a 403: Forbidden error when trying to deploy a test Flask app on GoDaddy. I've installed Python 3.5.7, and the files I've added/changed are:

1) created .htaccess in public_html:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule /home/myusername/public_html/python/cgi-bin/app.cgi/$1 [L]
```

2) created a virtual environment venv in cgi-bin and installed Flask

3) created app.cgi in public_html/cgi-bin:

```
#!/home/myusername/.local/bin/python3
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/myusername/public_html/cgi-bin/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
activate_this = '/home/myusername/public_html/cgi_bin/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
from app import app
class ProxyFix(object):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['SERVER_NAME'] = ""
        environ['SERVER_PORT'] = "80"
        environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "GET"
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ""
        environ['QUERY_STRING'] = ""
        environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = "HTTP/1.1"
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
    CGIHandler().run(app)
app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
CGIHandler.run(app)
```

4) created app.py in public_html/cgi-bin:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

5) created home.html in public_html/cgi-bin/templates

I've also modified the permissions to 755 for these various files.

Does anyone have any suggestions for where I might be going wrong? Thanks so much for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule /home/myusername/public_html/python/cgi-bin/app.cgi/$1 [L]
> ```

You are missing the *pattern* (first) argument to the `RewriteRule` directive - so this isn't doing anything. You should also be rewritting to a URL-path, not an absolute filesystem path. So, this should be something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule !^python/cgi-bin/app.cgi/ /python/cgi-bin/app.cgi%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Assuming `/public_html` is the document root directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But when I change to this, I now get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting a 404: page not found error.

Comment: Your `RewriteRule` implies your script is expecting input via PATH_INFO, although I can't immediately see how `app.cgi` would do this? Does this handler accept path-info?

Comment: How would I change app.cgi to utilize PATH_INFO input? Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: What URL are you requesting? Sorry, I'm new to Python myself. I know Apache/.htaccess. (To answer my question above... the cgi-script handler allows path-info by default, so that part is "OK" at least. If the handler did not allow path-info then that would also have generated a 404.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209811/discussion-between-user8222899-and-mrwhite).

Comment: I'm trying to render the main.py file